# Objects in S3 bucket are not replicated in target bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, replication

i have enabled replication for an s3 bucket using boto3 ,needed to enable KMS as well but when i try to test this functionality by uploading files manually in the source bucket, they don't get replicated in the destination bucket.

When i check the status of the replication on the console i can see that it's failing but we don't have the details on the cause.

FYI , we have an existing policy attached to the role i am using here and i updated it to reflect the bellow changes :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "greengrass:*",
                "wafv2:ListWebACLs",
                "iotevents:DeleteAlarmModel",
                "cloudfront:ListCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentities",
                "iotevents:UpdateAlarmModel",
                "iot:*",
                "cloudfront:DeleteCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity",
                "iotevents:ListAlarmModels",
                "iotsitewise:*",
                "iotevents:ListAlarms",
                "cloudfront:Get*",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iotevents:DescribeAlarm",
                "kinesisanalytics:DescribeApplication",
                "ses:SendEmail",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:ListKeys",
                "kinesisanalytics:ListApplications",
                "iotevents:DescribeAlarmModel",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "kms:GetKeyPolicy",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iotevents:CreateAlarmModel",
                "firehose:DescribeDeliveryStream",
                "kms:ListAliases",
                "servicequotas:*",
                "lambda:*",
                "route53:*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "cloudfront:ListDistributions",
                "firehose:ListDeliveryStreams",
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "cloudfront:DeleteDistribution",
                "kinesisanalytics:StartApplication",
                "acm:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:PutBucketEncryption"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor4",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete",
                "s3:ReplicateTags",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor5",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::id:role/fakereplicationrole"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor6",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::id:role/fakereplicationrole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is the code :

```
import boto3
import botocore
import logging

s3_client=boto3.client('s3')
kms_client = boto3.client('kms') 
my_region=s3_client.meta.region_name
region = my_region
storageClass = 'STANDARD'
prefix_filter = ''   
deleteMarkerReplication = 'Enabled'
existingObjectReplication = 'Enabled'


def get_role():
    """
    Description : get the role needed to enable the replication
    
    """
    response = boto3.client("iam").get_role(RoleName='fakerolename')
    arn=response['Role']['Arn']

    return arn
def get_versioning(bucket: str):
    """
    Description :check if the versioning is enabled for the source bucket , if not the function enables it
    Args : bucket(str)
    
    """
    # GET VERSIONING OF SOURCE BUCKET
    s3_client.get_bucket_versioning(Bucket=bucket)
    logging.info(f'Bucket "{bucket}" : enabling versioning')
    s3_client.put_bucket_versioning(Bucket=bucket, VersioningConfiguration={'Status': 'Enabled' })

def create_target_bucket(bucket: str):
    """
    Description : create the replicated bucket 
    Args : bucket(str) 
    
    """
    logging.info('Creating Target Bucket')
    s3_client.create_bucket( Bucket=f'{bucket}-target', CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': region,},)
    logging.info(f'Creating versioning for the target bucket "{bucket}-target" ')
    s3_client.put_bucket_versioning(Bucket=f'{bucket}-target', VersioningConfiguration={'Status': 'Enabled'},)

def enable_replication(bucket: str):
    """
    Description : enable replication for the source bucket 
    Args : bucket(str) 
    
    """
    logging.info(f'Inserting replication for the bucket "{bucket}" ')
    s3_client.put_bucket_replication(Bucket=bucket,
    #Modify the entry below with your account and the role you created
    ReplicationConfiguration={
    "Role": get_role(),
    "Rules": [
    {
    "Status": "Enabled",
    "Priority": 1,
    "Filter": {"Prefix": prefix_filter},
    "DeleteMarkerReplication": {"Status": deleteMarkerReplication},
    "Destination": {
        "Bucket": "arn:aws:s3:::%s-target" % bucket,"StorageClass": storageClass
    }
    
    }
    ]
    }
    )
    print(bucket)

def get_s3_kms_key():
    """
    Description : get the aws kms key for s3 
     
    
    """
    response = kms_client.list_aliases(Limit=123)
    target_key_id=[]
    for element in response['Aliases']:
        if 's3' in element['AliasName']:
            target_key_id.append(element['TargetKeyId'])
    
    return target_key_id[0]

def set_bucket_kms_encryption(bucket: str):
    """
    Description : enable kms encryption for the source bucket
    Args : bucket(str) 
    
    """
    s3_client.put_bucket_encryption(Bucket=bucket,
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration={
                'Rules': [
            {
                'ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault': {
                    'SSEAlgorithm': 'aws:kms',
                    'KMSMasterKeyID': get_s3_kms_key()
                },
                'BucketKeyEnabled': True
            }
        ]
        })
def create_s3_backupdata(bucketname: str):
    """
    Description : create the source bucket , enable replication and kms
    Args : bucketname(str) 
    
    """
    s3_client.create_bucket( Bucket=bucketname, CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': region})
    set_bucket_kms_encryption(bucket=bucketname)
    try:

        logging.info(f'Bucket "{bucketname}" already had replication')
        config=s3_client.get_bucket_replication(Bucket=bucketname)
        logging.info(f'bucket config "{config}" ')
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError:

# Log replication config
        logging.info(f'Bucket "{bucketname}" : Replication config not enabled. Will enable versioning on source bucket and create a replication config')
        # GET VERSIONING
        get_versioning(bucketname)
        # CREATE TARGET BUCKET
        create_target_bucket(bucketname)
        # Checking if config was created and skipping if not needed
        enable_replication(bucketname)

def main():
    bucketname='test1-kms-replication'
    create_s3_backupdata(bucketname)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: Did you read this S3 replication troubleshooting guide? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-replication/

Comment: hey Mark , thanks for your quick response , i already went through this link and tried to apply what's in it but i am still facing the same issue